# Problem in taking multiple input in a line

Tags: python-3.x

I want to take input like
+ 2 3
? 1 20
where the first variable is char and the next will be integers

I have done this

```
sign,m,n = input().split()
[sign,m,n]=[str(sign),int(m),int(n)]
```

But i get this error

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)

Comment: Cannot reproduce! Your code-snippet runs just fine.

Comment: I do not get that error with your input. I *do* get it when I press Enter without entering some text. Perhaps you forgot to enter something?

Comment: @ usr2564301
I face that every time when I press Enter both with and without value

Comment: @G-man
This also give me the same error

Comment: You can accomplish this task with this single line statement too: `sign, m, n = [c if i == 0 else int(c) for i, c in enumerate(input().split()[:3])]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in `sign,m,n = input().split()`. You have to treat as a list, not as function which returns 3 values.  Here it is a snippet code of what you desire:

```
stdin = input().split()
sign,m,n = str(stdin[0]),int(stdin[1]),int(stdin[2])
```

Stdin is a **list**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your own logic to get it done, then here is the way.

> Just append `[:3]` at the end of first statement to slice the list.

```
>>> sign, m, n = input().split()[:3]
+ 2 3 ? 1 20
>>>
>>> [sign,m,n] = [str(sign), int(m), int(n)]
>>>
>>> sign
'+'
>>>
>>> m
2
>>>
>>> n
3
>>>
```

And here is another way to accomplish the same in a single line.

> For this you can use the concept of list comprehension.

```
>>> sign, m, n = [c if i == 0 else int(c) for i, c in enumerate(input().split()[:3])]
+ 2 3 ? 1 20
>>>
>>> sign
'+'
>>> m
2
>>> n
3
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding the enclosing square paranthesis in your first statement works on Python 3.6.7 :

```
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> [sign,m,n] = input().split()
- 2 3
>>> [sign,m,n] = [str(sign),int(m),int(n)]
>>> sign
'-'
>>> m
2
>>> n
3
```

Comment: Yeah. This works also.
Can you tell me how this square parenthesis works at this?